# ld.so.preload ignored in Debian 10?

Tags: linux, debian, shared-library

When I try to put something simple that hooks functions compiled as a shared library in /etc/ld.so.preload I expect it to have  the same effect as using LD_PRELOAD.

Instead, nothing happens. It is almost like Debian 10 ignores ld.so.preload. When I do the exact same thing on an old Slackware box, it works fine.

When did Debian 10 stop using ld.so.preload? How do I enable it again?

I'm compiling with `gcc -shared -fPIC`, and this happens for everything I try to do. As I said, it works on Slackware, so why not Debian?

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/ld.so.preload` is not ignored by Debian 10. If I write `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3` (a single line) into it on my system, `$ LD_DEBUG=files sleep 1` reports it back.

Comment: If I just write something that hooks rand to always return 42,  and then do echo "/root/rand.so" > /etc/ld.so.preload and then try to use rand to generate a random number, I get 42 in Debian 9, but in Debian 10, I get a real random number. ld.so.preload doesn't work in Debian 10.